# Search Bar results filter php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm making an E-Commerce site. I want to filter the products based on the text in the search box.

The 'products' table:

```
products
id| type_id | brand_id | cat_id | title| desc
```

I want to check if the result_text is present in type_name or brand_name or cat_name and show all the products based on it.

Answer (score 1):

I will you are using MySQL for your database and that type_id, brand_id and cat_id are foreign keys.

In MySQL you have a nice keyword called `LIKE`. Then you also have joins which help you fetch data from related tables

So you need a query like

```
SELECT products.*, types.* /* other tables here */ 
FROM products LEFT JOIN types on products.type_id = types.id /* other joins here */
WHERE types.type_name LIKE '%/* variable here */%' OR brands.brand_name LIKE '%/* variable here */%' /* other conditions */
```

Comment: That is my mistake. I haven't made any of these foreign keys.    Then what should I do?

Comment: In case you don't know about them, read this, good article: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: I know the relations but I just forgot to add them as foreign key and I have also proceeded with everything and then so I would have to change all the code. So is there any way that I can filter the results without making them as foreign keys.

Comment: The query should be the same but unless you indexed the _id columns it will be very slow